# When is tomorrow when I want to accept my own answer?

Tags: discussion, support, status-bydesign, accepted-answer, self-answer

[My understanding](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5782/44179) is that SE runs on UTC time and resets at 0:00 UTC.  That means the day resets at 4:00 Pacific Standard Time where I am.

"Yesterday" (before four o'clock) when I tried to accept my own answer it told me "You can accept your own answer tomorrow"

[image]

However, it is now past four o'clock, so a new UTC day, and I still get this message.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: "Tomorrow" isn't a great term. "1 days time" would be much less confusing

Comment: @RichardTingle "In 48 hours" would be more even better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That message is not based off the new day whatsoever. You have to wait at least 48 hours from the time you posted your question before you can accept your own answer to it. So, to figure out when you can accept the answer, look at the user card in your question, hover over the time to get the exact timestamp in the tooltip, and add 48 hours to it.

Comment: So the wording "tomorrow" is incorrect then, isn't it?

Comment: @Asad: Not incorrect, just vague.

Comment: Why does the 48 hour restriction exist in the first place?

Comment: To let other users the time to give an answer which could be better than your.

Comment: @RichardPayne early on in stackoverflow history, people would ask simple questions like how to add one to a number in lisp and then immediatly answer them for "internet points".  hence the cooling off period

Comment: lol, ok.  So now you have to be a cool, calculated and patient points hunter rather than a hot head?  ;-)

Comment: @chollida I have to say it would be quite easy to automate detection of people who abuse the system and take appropriate action. I just answered one of my own questions after 24 hours, and I would like to fully close this issue now, not having to worry about coming back tomorrow to clean things up.